# Proof that the dimension of the image of a transformation is the rank of the matrix that induces this transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

If $T$ is a transformation, we can write $T(v)=Av$, where $A$ is the matrix that induces that transformation on $v$.

We were asked for a rigorous proof of the question I mentioned above, and I was completely blank. I always assumed it was a *de facto* thing.

How do I go about proving this?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the dimension of a vector space? Likewise, of the rank of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

For a  square matrix $A$, the rank of $A$ is the rank of its column vectors, and these generate the image of the associated linear map.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, although I don't know whether it can be called a proof. T(v)=Av and Av is always a vector in the column space of A. So dimension of the image of T i.e. Av is the dimension of column space of A, which is the rank.

Comment: It was just a hint, but your argumentation is quite fine.

Comment: Oh, my bad haha. My first sentence was referring to what I was writing subsequently, not what you wrote. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, your comment gives a fine proof for me.